# How do I find the position of a (fuzzy) match within a string?

Tags: r, string, text

I have a text processing problem in R. I want to get the character within a string where a different string makes an exact match and/or a fuzzy match with some edit distance. For example:

```
A = "blahmatchblah"
B = "match"
C = "latch"
```

I would like to return something telling me that the 5th character within string A is where the match for a search of both B and C. All the pattern matching tools I'm aware of will tell me if there's a (fuzzy) match for B and C within A, but none for where that match begins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base function `aregexec()` is used for approximate string position matching. Unfortunately it's not vectorized over `pattern`, so we'll have to use a loop to get the positions for both `B` and `C`.

```
sapply(c(B, C), aregexec, A)
# $match
# [1] 5
# attr(,"match.length")
# [1] 5
#
# $latch
# [1] 5
# attr(,"match.length")
# [1] 5
```

See `help(aregexec)` for more.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have rep to comment but at least for the first part of your question: gregexpr(B,A)[[1]][1] will yield 5 because "match" is a valid sub-sequence in A.

Answer (score 0):

A few months back I made an interface to the [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/mlampros/fuzzywuzzyR) Python package in R, which has the **get_matching_blocks()** method (it's pretty close to what you actually ask).

Assuming you want to find the matching blocks between two strings,

```
A = "blahmatchblah"
B = "match"

library(fuzzywuzzyR)

init <- SequenceMatcher$new(string1 = A, string2 = B)

init$get_matching_blocks()
```

returns,

```
[[1]]
Match(a=4, b=0, size=5)

[[2]]
Match(a=13, b=5, size=0)
```

The first sublist gives the matching blocks of the two strings. **a = 4** gives the starting index of the string **A** and **b=0** gives the starting index of the string **B** (indexing starts from 0). **size = 5** gives the count of characters that both strings match (in this case the matching block is "match" and has 5 characters).

The [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fuzzywuzzyR/fuzzywuzzyR.pdf), especially for *SequenceMatcher*, has more info.